# DateTime column in RadGrid Excel exporting in Military Time

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgrid

So I have a RadGrid that has a column of a DateTime. In the grid It will show up as 12/31/13 12:00:00 AM which is perfect. But when I export to Excel, it shows up as 12/31/13 0:00.

Is there a way to change this in the VB.NET or should I just deal with it being in Military Time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code taken from the C# solution below:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-export-to-excel-date-format

You'll obviously need to add the ExcelExportCellFormatting event to your RadGrid and modify the "UniqueName" to your DateTime column's uniquename.

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_ExcelExportCellFormatting(source As Object, e As ExcelExportCellFormattingEventArgs)
  If (e.FormattedColumn.UniqueName) = "UniqueName" Then
    e.Cell.Style("mso-number-format") = "m\/d\/yy\ h\:mm\ AM\/PM"
  End If
End Sub
```